# getFilesDir() vs getExternalFilesDir(), which one is more recommended?

Tags: java, android, android-file

As far as I've noticed, using `getFilesDir()` to store data (camera captures in my case) is somewhat temporary. I say somewhat because if I close and reopen the app, I'm able to access the directory and file list, but not the file itself.

Is my logic wrong or is that by design?
Out of the 2 methods, which is more recommended in:

1. general
2. my case (privacy is needed)

Comment: [this link](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage) say getFileDir is app specific and no other app cant read files in this dir.
but when use getExternalFileDir all apps can read files in this dir

Comment: "using getFilesDir() to store data (camera captures in my case) is somewhat temporary" -- it is not temporary. "I say somewhat because if I close and reopen the app, I'm able to access the directory and files list, but not the file itself" -- please provide a [mcve] showing your code that implements the "access the directory and files list, but not the file itself" logic. "Out of the 2 methods, which is more recommended in" -- `getFilesDir()`, unless the user needs independent access to the content.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply, 
**getFilesDir()** refers to internal storage that cannot be accessible outside your application. It's not explorable by the device as well.

getExternalFilesDir() refers to external storage, it's a type of App-specific storage. this can be explorable as you find its directory in

***data/data/your package name***

In general, you may use external storage as internal storage may be limited.

For privacy, if you need you to file security, use **getFilesDir()** as it's not accessible outside your application as I mentioned before.

Answer (score 3):

**Update for the latest Android (currently Android 14)**

In the old days `getFilesDir()` used to mean internal storage, and `getExternalFilesDir()` used to mean anything plugged in (usually an SD card).

These days phones don't have SD card slots, so the device emulates external storage by grabbing a slice of internal storage for the purpose. So the historic differences - that internal was faster and smaller, and external slower and larger - are generally no longer true.

In both cases apps get **scoped** storage - i.e. a directory they can access without permissions, which isn't accessible by any other app (though see below). This has been the case since Android 10 (but only enforced in Android 11).

Files stored under `getFilesDir()` and `getExternalFilesDir()` will be deleted when the app is uninstalled, but will persist until then. (If you're finding a file disappears before then, you have a different problem. I would suggest posting your code in a separate question).

The only major remaining difference between internal and external is that apps *can* get request a permission to read/write the entirety of external storage, including files it doesn't own. So don't use external for files that need to remain private to the app.

More information in this article: https://medium.com/@tdcolvin/demystifying-internal-vs-external-storage-in-modern-android-c9c31cb8eeec

Comment: My year-old phone (Redmi 10C) has an SD card slot. Or it has a tray where I can put both an SD card and a SIM card, if that makes a difference. Would that be treated as the external or would Android still do the emulated external on my phone?

Comment: @hippietrail most likely external. But try it and let us know! Genuinely interested to hear, there's not a lot of current phones out there with SD card slots, so very little opportunity to try it out

Comment: Does that mean that `getFilesDir()` and `getExternalFilesDir()` have different storage space ? if yes which of the 2 folders is bigger ?
EDIT: I've tried it out on my phone, the 2 have the same totalSpace and freeSpace

Comment: @Biscuit They definitely *could* have different storage space because they could refer to different drives altogether. E.g. in the case where the phone has internal memory and and SD card slot. But more recent phones only have internal memory, and the external is simulated using that. So it reports the same free+total space for it, because it's the same drive. More info in the article I linked above.

Comment: I have run some more test with a tablet that has SD card and turns out `getExternalFilesDir` return the emulated memory.

Comment: To make sure the file is emulated there is `Environment#isExternalStorageEmulated(File)`

Comment: Ok this is where it gets complicated. What you're seeing is probably _adopted_ external storage. That's where the OS uses the SD card and internal memory together as one big drive. It's a strategy for handling small internal storage and a way of having apps installed which take up more space than is available on just the internal.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between the two is:
getFilesDir() - This path will be hidden from the user. This is more secure approach.
getExternalFilesDir() - Accessible by the user.

Received a good documentation on this which provides clear understanding:
http://androidvogella.blogspot.com/2015/12/getfilesdir-vs-getexternalfilesdir-vs.html